# SplitApp is displayed not correct

Tags: routes, sapui5

I try to build a SplitApp, but cannot figure out what's wrong with my routing: the master page is displayed as details page, the details page is not displayed at all. It looks like I use not SplitApp, but App.

[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fikhX.png) how the application looks like.

Here is my App.view.xml:

```js
<mvc:View controllerName="test.controller.App" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
    <SplitApp id="app"/>

</mvc:View>
```

Here is my routing and root view declaration from the Component.js (I use version 1.28.1):

```js
"rootView": {
                viewName: "test.view.App",
                type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
},
"routing": {
                "config": {
                    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "viewPath": "test.view",
                    "controlId": "app",
                    "controlAggregation": "detailPages",
                    "bypassed": {
                        "target": ["master", "notFound"]
                    }
                },

                "routes": [{
                    "pattern": "",
                    "name": "master",
                    "target": ["object", "master"]
                }, {
                    "pattern": "Details",
                    "name": "object",
                    "target": ["master", "object"]
                }],

                "targets": {
                    "master": {
                        "viewName": "Master",
                        "viewLevel": 1,
                        "viewId": "master",
                        "controlAggregation": "masterPages"

                    },
                    "object": {
                        "viewName": "Detail",
                        "viewId": "detail",
                        "viewLevel": 2
                    }
                }
            }
```

What do I miss?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
The SplitApp looks like I have described in this post on a Laptop with high resolution. The same app on another pc with a lower resolution display is shown as it should - with master and detail parts.

How this issue can be explaned and fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared aggregations `detailPages` and `masterPages` for `SplitApp` control? They're used in routing, but I don't see them in the view.

I suppose you might want to try something like this:

```
<SplitApp id="app">
  <masterPages>
    <Page>
      ...
    </Page>
  </masterPages>
  <detailPages>
    <Page>
      ...
    </Page>
  </detailPages>
</SplitApp>
```

I think this is also a relevant example: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.SplitApp/code

Comment: as far as I understand, those aggregations should be declared automatically when the router is initialized in the component.js. Those aggregations are declared under "controlAggregation" property.